# Laravel 5.2 - Blade - How to get the iteration key inside of an @each()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

So I am trying to use the `@each` [Laravel Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade) method in a view but I really need the current itteration that were on. Obviously in a @foreach I would just do `$key => $value` and use the $key. Any idea if this can be done with @each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look under the hood:

https://github.com/illuminate/view/blob/master/Factory.php#L266 (line 266)

Just a guess, but based on the source code, you could try:

```
@each ('show.names', $names, 'name');
```

And in a partial:

```
echo $key; // or $name['key'] or $name->key...
```

Or try to `dd($name)` and look for a key in a result.

Comment: thanks! I was having a hard time tracking down that factory class.